# AIRFLOW - Setting relationships from a list of operators

Tags: python, list, airflow

I have a list of operators that were appended to a list in a for loop. I would like to set a relationship for my DAG where each task is set downstream in the order of the list. For example

```
task_list = []
for operator in operator_array:
    task = operator
    task_list.append(task)

# theoretically I would want something like this:

some_other_operator >> task_list[0] >> task_list[1] >> task_list[2] and so on and so forth for however long the length of the list is
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a helper function created for that, will be much more performant than the accepted answer

See [airflow.utils.helpers](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.3/_modules/airflow/utils/helpers.html) module

```
from airflow.utils.helpers import chain

chain(*task_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a list of tasks named `task_list`, you can do:

```
some_other_operator >> task_list[0]

for i in range(len(task_list) - 1):
    task_list[i] >> task_list[i + 1]
```

Comment: oh no im getting this error airflow.exceptions.AirflowDagCycleException: Cycle detected in DAG.

Comment: maybe `some_other_operator` is one of tasks in `task_list`? Could you try to run it without the first line just to make sure that this is not the problem?